# apt-cacher-ng altenative for windows package manager Chocolatey

Tags: windows, proxy, package-managers, chocolatey

Is there any `apt-cacher-ng` alternative for  windows package manager, Chocolatey?
I want to setup a proxy(such a apt-cacher-ng for Linux) in my private LAN for proxing Chocolatey.

Every node in private network has no access to internet, they can connect to this proxy and it acts as Chocolatey Server.

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the nature of Chocolatey packages, I.e. reaching out to the internet to download the native installers for an application, simply caching the nupkg locally isn’t enough, as an internet connection would still be required.  This is due to the distribution rights assigned to the native installers of that application.

Some packages on chocolatey.org are what are known as embedded packages. These are packages whose applications allow the distribution of the installers.  In these cases, the nupkg contains everything that is required. As such, these nupkgs can be directly cached locally and they will work without an internet connection.

For the first type of packages, you would need to go through a process of what is called internalisation. This is documented here:

https://chocolatey.org/docs/how-to-recompile-packages

With OSS Chocolatey this is a manual process, but with Chocolatey for Business there is a tool that can perform this automatically.